# problem with VBA Find function in cells with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a find function, it is supposed to look for "2021" in the range DP.

```vb
Range(DP).Find("2021", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0) = t
```

2021 is in range but it is the result of a formula.
(Cell A2 in range DP is `=$B$5` and `B5=2021`)

All ranges and variables are defined and the code works perfectly.
However, every once in while, I get the "'Run-time Error '91'"!!
I press debug, vba page opens and the Find function is the issue. (the value isn't found)
And the best part is, if I delete a random letter of the code and rewrite the EXACT same letter (basically changing NOTHING), and close vba and run again, the code works again without errors!!!

Any idea how to fix this bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends what datatype is in the cell. If it is a number (2021), then you shouldn't search for a string ("2021").

Comment: Not seeing the rest of your code, I assume that it works on the active sheet. Are you sure that the necessary sheet is activated when the problem occurs? I suppose that `DP` is a string address. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is `DP`? A string or a name (object)? If the cell (row and/or column) containing `2021` or `"2021"` (`'2021`) is hidden, it will not be found with `xlValues` hence rather use `xlFormulas`. But this won't work since `2021` is the result of a formula, so I guess you should stick with `xlValues` and make sure that the cells of the range are not hidden. Note that both options will fail if the worksheet is filtered (remove the filter). BTW, you can always loop through the cells of the range or write the values of the range to an array and loop through the elements of the array.

Comment: @GSerg `Find("2021")` will find numeric values too.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are correct. I confused it with vlookup.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to define the worksheet

   ```
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(DP)
   ```
2. Make sure `DP` is a defined variable (use `Option Explicit`) or if you meant to use column `DP` then make sure it is a string `Range("DP")`.

So maybe it should look something like

```
Dim t As String
t = "test"

Dim DP As String
DP = "A:A"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(DP).Find("2021", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0) = t
```

or something like this

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("DP").Find("2021", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0) = "t"
```